# Fastcgi wrapper not working with root permisions

Tags: wrapper, root, fastcgi

i have problem setting fastcgi wrapper to execute commands from web as root

only settings i have changed

```
FCGI_USER="root"
FCGI_GROUP="root"


[....] Starting FastCGI wrapper: fcgiwrapspawn-fcgi: I will not set uid to 0
```

failed!

i want to manipulate with gpio through web with wiringPi, but wiringPisetup requires root access

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spawn-fcgi (https://github.com/lighttpd/spawn-fcgi) is the problem.

Apply this patch to src/spawn-fcgi.c and recompile spawn-fcgi. In my case I wanted to run nmap -sS which requires root. It really grinds my gears when developers decide to make running as root impossible because it's just a waste of everyone's time. Always add a flag, call it --super-insecure if you want to but at least put it there!

```
diff --git a/src/spawn-fcgi.c b/src/spawn-fcgi.c
index 2f320f7..27176d5 100644
--- a/src/spawn-fcgi.c
+++ b/src/spawn-fcgi.c
@@ -385,10 +385,10 @@ static int find_user_group(const char *user, const char *group, uid_t *uid, gid_
                        }
                        my_uid = my_pwd->pw_uid;

-                       if (my_uid == 0) {
+                       /*if (my_uid == 0) {
                                fprintf(stderr, "spawn-fcgi: I will not set uid to 0\n");
                                return -1;
-                       }
+                       }*/

                        if (username) *username = user;
                } else {
@@ -407,18 +407,18 @@ static int find_user_group(const char *user, const char *group, uid_t *uid, gid_
                        }
                        my_gid = my_grp->gr_gid;

-                       if (my_gid == 0) {
+                       /*if (my_gid == 0) {
                                fprintf(stderr, "spawn-fcgi: I will not set gid to 0\n");
                                return -1;
-                       }
+                       }*/
                }
        } else if (my_pwd) {
                my_gid = my_pwd->pw_gid;

-               if (my_gid == 0) {
+               /*if (my_gid == 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "spawn-fcgi: I will not set gid to 0\n");
                        return -1;
-               }
+               }*/
        }

        *uid = my_uid;
```